# How to close realm opened by Realm.getDefaultInstance?

Tags: android, realm

I am using realm to store and retrieve data. Usually when we open a realm to store some data we do like:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.beginTransaction();
// Copy the object to Realm
realm.copyToRealm(myObject);
realm.commitTransaction();
realm.close();
```

in the above case I am closing the realm.

But when I am retrieving some data like:

```
RealmResults<MyClass> results = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(MyClass.class).findAll();
```

How do I close this realm? Does it need to be closed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Doing it as a one-liners means you cannot close the Realm, so I would advice against that.

Not closing the Realm will in the best case cause you to leak memory and have a higher chance of being killed by the system if the in the background. Worst case you will see a high increase in disk usage because Realm has to keep track of all versions of opened Realm instances (due to being a MVCC database).

I would highly advice using your first pattern. For more information about controlling the Realm instances you can read this: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realm-instance-lifecycle and this https://realm.io/news/threading-deep-dive/

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: But what about the warning in Logcat yelling `Remember to call close() on all Realm instances. Realm /data/data/com.foo.bar/files/default.realm is being finalized without being closed, this can lead to running out of native memory.`?

Comment: Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        int comLog = realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(CommitLog.class)
                .equalTo("conversationId", cache.getConversationId())
                .findFirst()).getCommitMessages().size();
        realm.close();

what if i do like this, and if it cause any leak or lead null pointer exception ?